# Unable to get the return from php in ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I just want to get back some return value from the ajax data post. I am not sure why I am not getting something back in success. Please review the code and tell me where I am wrong

My jquery code

```
$("#btnlogin").click(function(){

    var email = $("#emaillog").val();
    var password = $("#passlog").val();
    console.log('test');
    /* $.ajax({
        url: 'home2/login_user',
        //data: {'title': title},  change this to send js object
        type: "post", 
        data: 'email=' + email+'&password='+password,
        success: function(output) {
            url:"home2/login_user",
            data: 'email=' + email+'&password='+password,
            alert(output);
        }
    });*/

    $.ajax ({
         url:"home2/login_user",
         type: "post",
         dataType: 'json', 
         data: 'email=' + email+'&password='+password,
         success: function (data) {
             $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                 console.log(key,'--',value);
             });
              //iterate here the object
         }
     });
});
```

My php code

```
public function Login_user()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $data['result'] = $this->Home_model->login_to_user($email,$password); 
        echo json_encode ($data['result']);     


    }
```

In php code I echo the result but in in jquery. I am not getting any result in success

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(data)` in the success callback?

Comment: I got nothing in console log it is not going in success.. @MartinGottweis

Comment: Maybe the url is wrong? Can you access `home2/login_user` in your browser?

Comment: No url is correct @MartinGottweis

Comment: i believe the problem is most probably that the php code is not returning a valid json as @dimlucas suggested

Answer (score 1):

use parseJSON

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
console.log(obj.key);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because your backend code does not seem to be able to find the username and password parameters. You're passing them the wrong way at this line of code:

`data: 'email=' + email+'&password='+password,`

Replace the string with a JavaScript object:

`data: { email: email, password: password }`

Answer (score 0):

well, first, you are passing the parameters like it was a get request, and its not.

Change the way you passing to something like this.

```
 $.ajax ({
         url:"home2/login_user",
         type: "post",
         dataType: 'json', 
         data: { field1: "hello", field2 : "hello2"},
         success: function (data) {
             $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                 console.log(key,'--',value);
             });
              //iterate here the object
         }
     });
```